# Deleting a Node in a Linked List in C++

Tags: c++, linked-list, nodes, delete-operator

I am trying to delete a node in a singly linked list at the nth position of the list, but I keep receiving a segmentation fault:11 when running the project. Below is my function `remove` where I believe the problem is, but I can not seem to figure why its not working because the logic makes sense. Also  where `headM` points as in the first item in the list is the 0th position. 
Before I make the call to remove my list is the order `770 440 330 220 110`
I make two calls to remove

```
remove(0)
remove(2)
```

the list after should be `440 330 110`, but right now I am getting `770 330 110`....

```
void SimpleList::remove(int n)
{
if( n < 0 || n > sizeM ) { 
    return;
}
Node* p = headM;
for( int c = 0; c < n - 1; c++ )
{
    p = p->next;
    //assert( p != nullptr );
}
Node* const p_doomed = p->next;
//assert( p_doomed != nullptr );
p->next = p_doomed->next;
delete p_doomed;
--sizeM;
}
```

And below is the structure of the node. This part is correct because my `push_front` and `push_back` work.

```
class Node {
public:
    ListItem item;
    Node *next;
};

Node *headM;
int sizeM;

void destroy();
// Deallocate all nodes, and sets headM to zero.

void copy(const SimpleList& source);
// List becomes copy of source.
```

Comment: Did you consider a redesign and the use of std::list? This would save time.

Answer (score 0):

You do not check whether a node is equal to nullptr and sizeM is not decreased in case a node was deleted

The function can be written the following way

```
size_t sizeM;

//...

void SimpleList::remove( size_t n )
{
    Node *current = headM;
    Node *prev    = nullptr;

    while ( current && n-- )
    {
        prev    = current;
        current = current->next;
    }

    if ( current )
    {
        if ( prev ) prev->next = current->next;
        else headM = headM->next;

        delete current;
        --sizeM;
    }
}
```

I suppose that indices of the list start from zero.

Take into account that `sizeM` should be defined as `size_t` instead of `int`. Declaring it as `int` has no sense, in this case you shall always check whether `sizeM` is less than zero. Also you could define a more general type for `sizeM`. For example

```
typedef size_t size_type;
```

And if `headM` and `sizeM` are global variables then it would be better to encapsulate `headM` and `sizeM` in a separate class for example named as `List`.

Also you could check in the function whether the index is greater than or equal to `sizeM`. If it is indeed is greater than or equal to `sizeM` then you can either simp0ly exit from the function or throw an exceprion.

For example

```
void SimpleList::remove( size_t n )
{
    if ( !( b < sizeM ) ) return;
```

or

```
void SimpleList::remove( size_t n )
{
    if ( !( b < sizeM ) ) throw std::out_of_range( "Incorrect value of the index" );
```

Comment: "Take into account that sizeM should be defined as size_t instead of int" is very bad advice. It has no advantages. And it encourages bugs.

Comment: @Cheers and hth. - Alf  I advice you to write a proposal to C++ Committee that they would change all standard containers by substituting their size_type for int instead of size_t.:)

Comment: That's impractical, it would break an enormous amount of code (which is the reason why it is as it is). Blindly following a convention without understanding it, is ungood. OK to do it yourself, but please don't foist it on others, in particular not on beginners.

Comment: not really quite sure as to why I would need size_t when I am passing an int as an argument to the function..?

Comment: @tom smith  Because it is simply silly. You should use that types that have appropriate ranges of values. Otherwise you shall in all your code check whether its value is less than zero. Moreover you also shall to write a comment that users may not enter negative values. Is not it silly?:) When a programmer defines such objects as having type int then this says only that he has low quakification a s a programmer an nothing more.

Comment: @Cheers and hth. - Alf I try to help others to improve their quakification and do not do stupidies.:)

Comment: @VladfromMoscow: I think, in your answer to tom smith, it would be better to list some perceived advantage of this choice, which after all has definite known costs such as implicit conversions to unsigned with modulo arithmetic, than to just say that the ordinary best practice, e.g. as advocated by Bjarne, is silly.

Comment: @Cheers and hth. - Alf Bjarne is very weak practical programmer. It is enough to mention that due to his petty tyranny programmers have no standard algorithm std::copy_if. His code in his books is usuaaly an example of how the code shhould not be written.:)

Answer (score 0):

Consider the last node, e.g., if the list has (i) nodes: {0 .. i - 1}, then the node at position (i - 1). You should be able to satisfy yourself that after the loop:

```
for(int c = 0; c < n; c++) p = p->next; // where: n = i - 1
```

`p->next` is `NULL` (or `nullptr`), therefore:

`p->next = p->next->next;` dereferences a null pointer.

Answer (score 0):

The way you delete is a bit wrong. You would have to get the previous pointer's `next` node to the succeeding node of `p`, then delete it.

Anyway, you can also write it like this:

```c++
void SimpleList::remove(int value)
{
    Node** ptr = &headM, *next;

    while (*ptr && (*ptr)->data != value)
        ptr = &(*ptr)->next;

    if (*ptr)
    {    
        next = (*ptr)->next;
        delete *ptr;
        *ptr = next;
    }
}
```

And like Vlad said, you should decrement the size as well.

Answer (score 0):

<sup>***This answer is now invalidated by new information in the OP's question. As it turns out he doesn't have a dummy header node (as was implied by naming and logic), and the n in (quote) “nth” is not 1-based but a 0-based index. I'm leaving the answer as it was, preferring to not chase a changing question.***</sup>

This original code

```
void SimpleList::remove(int n)
{
    Node *p = headM;
    for(int c=0;c<n;c++)
    {
        p = p->next;
    }
    Node *todel = p->next;
    p->next = p->next->next;
    delete todel; 
}
```

implies that `headM` points to a dummy header node.

Considering what happens with `n` = 1, the `todel` is incorrectly set to `p->next`, the node after the one you want to delete. For that matter, you couldn't do very much with `p` pointing directly to the node you want to delete, unless you were guaranteed at least one following node and no other pointers into the list. Also, the `p->next->next` expression then can have UB even if the list contains `n` nodes (exactly).

Instead do like this:

```
void SimpleList::remove( int const n )
{
    if( n <= 0 || n > sizeM ) { throw std::runtime_error( "Ouch!" ); }
    Node* p = headM;
    for( int c = 1; c <= n - 1; ++c )
    {
        p = p->next;
        assert( p != nullptr );
    }
    Node* const p_doomed = p->next;
    assert( p_doomed != nullptr );
    p->next = p_doomed->next;
    delete p_doomed;
    --sizeM;
}
```

Comment: I commented out the assert because I was receiving a undeclared identifier error I edited the code in the original list but I seem to still not be getting the right output. details are above in edited original post

Comment: Also why are you decrementing or adding from the left as in ++c, or --sizeM rather than c++ or sizeM-- ?

Comment: @tomsmith: If `nullptr` is unknown to the compiler, you can either request the compiler to follow the C++11 standard, or replace `nullptr` with `0`. If `assert` is unknown to the compiler, include `<assert.h>` (do that anyway). In general, please be more precise: "undeclared identifier" is needlessly vague, compared to mentioning *which* identifier. Regarding `++c`, that expresses exactly the intent. The expression `c++` in addition asks for the original value, which is not used, and thus, meaningless.

Comment: also lastly why did you declare p_doomed as a 'const' type, does that make a difference or is that just good practice?

Comment: @tomsmith: that's just good practice. sprinkle `const` as liberally as you can throughout the code, because that tells a reader about what the code is guaranteed not to do (so less effort to figure out what it does). it also tends to help with catching mistakes such as writing `=` instead of `==`.